# output lines without multiple patterns

Tags: grep

I used `cat file | grep -v "pat1" | grep -v "pat2" | ... | grep -v "patN"` to drop lines with any of a group of patterns. It looks awkward. Is there a better (concise) way to do that?

Comment: try this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19467/using-grep-v-on-multiple-arguments

Answer (score 1):

In case you are ok with `awk` you could try following. Created a variable named `valIgnore` which has all the values to be ignored, you can mention all values by comma separated fashion and have them in it. By doing this you can give N number of keywords in a single shot only in a variable itself. Moreover you can also create a shell variable which has all values to be ignored(in lines) make sure its comma separated and pass it to this `awk` program here. Since no samples are given so didn't test it but should work though.

```
awk -v valIgnore="pat1,pat2,pat3,pat4,pat5,pat6,pat7,pat8,pat9" '
BEGIN{
  num=split(valIgnore,arr,",")
  for(i=1;i<=num;i++){ ignoreVals[arr[i]] }
}
{
  for(key in ignoreVals){
     if(index($0,key)){ next }
  }
}
1' Input_file
```

Comment: @Lee, Hello, could you please do let me know if my answer has helped you? Thank you.